# How to open a file in bundle in iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, safari

I wanna open a file in App bundle in Safari same as open a file from server in Safari.

For example: open pdf file in Safari like this way:

```
NSURL *urlNeedToOpen = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlNeedToOpen];
```

I download and copy pdf-test.pdf file to my bundle and try to open like this:

```
NSURL *urlNeedToOpen = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf-test" ofType:@"pdf"]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlNeedToOpen];
```

But nothing happen, I can preview this pdf file by UIDocumentInteractionController like this:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:urlNeedToOpen];
docController.delegate = self;
[docController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

But that's not I want, I want open file in bundle directly by Safari. Can I?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, no you can't open a local file URL in your application's bundle resources in another app - even Safari. The reason for this is that the resource is in your app's sandbox - it would violate the security framework of iOS for Safari to get access to it. This is working by design (apart from canOpenURL: should really make it more obvious that no other app can open it. You may want to consider filing a bug at: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

You may want to consider opening the local resource in a View Controller hosting a text view or webview instead if you absolutely have to distribute the resource inside your app's bundle.